# R shiny: 2 columns overlap when I make the browser smaller

Tags: r, shiny

I have a 2 column app written in R shiny. However, when I make the browser smaller, the text of the two columns will first overlap, and if I continue to make the browser smaller, then the columns get stacked into one column. Is there a way to modify the app such that when I make the browser smaller I get to retain the two column structure?

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp( ui =
  shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  }),

  server = 
  shinyUI(fluidPage(

    column(5,
           h3("Testingggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg")
    ),

    column(5, offset = 1,
           h3("Testingggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg"))

  ))
)
```

So when the browser is maximized, the app looks like this:

[image: Maximized]

when I minimize the browser a bit, I get:

[image]

and when I minimize more, I get:

[image]

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's completely a HTML/CSS issue, nothing to do with shiny. I suggest you read a bit about css and particular the `word-wrap` property.  Basically, the columns really are getting smaller, and if you would put any whitespace in the text you would see that it goes to a new line at the appropriate place.  But the HTML by default does not break up a word into multiple lines, which means that if you have a super long word it would actually overflow unless you specifically tell it to break it up.  You need to add the `word-wrap: break-word;` CSS rule to do that.

```
shinyApp( ui =
  shinyUI(fluidPage(
    tags$head(tags$style(
      "body { word-wrap: break-word; }"
    )),

    column(5,
           h3("Testingggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg")
    ),

    column(5, offset = 1,
           h3("Testingggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg"))

  )),
  server = function(input, output) {}
)
```

edit: here's a GIF I took to show it works

[image]

Comment: this does not solve the problem, when I minimize the browser, the two columns just stack on top of each other. I want to get the same behavior as when I make the browser smaller on the stackoverflow website.

Comment: it shouldn't, and it doesn't for me. See my edit, I added a GIF showing me making the window smaller/bigger and the columns don't overlap. What browser are you on? Again, this is purely a CSS issue (not related to shiny at all) so maybe there's something weird with your browser.

Comment: I'm using chrome. I'm getting the behavior as yours. But how do I get the same behavior as when I do the same thing on the stackoverflow website. When I do it on the SO website, I get the option to scroll to the left or scroll to the right.

Comment: oh well you could have been more clear about what you meant both in the question and in your comment, you made it sound like my solution didn't do anything. You should ask and tag with html/css to get people experts in css to answer if that's what you want

Answer (score -1):

Well, maybe if you try to add some CSS, you can visualize the information, correctly. A great library is: http://rstudio.github.io/shinythemes/

```
`library("shinythemes")`
theme = shinytheme("cerulean")
```

You have multiple options to do that, Bootstrap is a great solution for you.

Comment: css is the correct approach, but using a specific theme has nothing to do with it. It's just the default behaviour of browsers, you can override it with the `word-wrap: break-word` css rule

Comment: Glad to know the specific solution! I hadn't time to check it and to test and suggested a possible solution! ;)